# batch goto :eof not working when called from java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a batch file roughly with the following code:

```bash
@echo off
(
    set /p x=
    set /p y=
) < settings.cdb

IF DEFINED x (
    IF DEFINED y (
        ECHO true
        GoTo :EOF
    )
)
ECHO false
GoTo :EOF
```

In Java, I have the following code to call the batch file via command line:

```java
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process pr = probuilder.start();

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
{
    lines.add(line);
}
```

**X** and **Y** are some input parameters from a configuration file, which may, or may not, contain any data.

When **x** or **y** are not defined everything works as suppose, outputs `false`.

The problem comes when the variables are both defined.
When the batch file gets called via command line I get the resulting output: `true`. 
Which is the intend output.

When I call the same batch file via Java Process I get the following output:`false`. 
Which is not what I want.

Removing the `@echo off` I get the following output from running the batch file from command line:

```
IF DEFINED x (IF DEFINED y (
ECHO true
 GoTo :EOF
) )
true
```

But when I run it from Java Process:

```
IF DEFINED x (IF DEFINED y (
ECHO true  
 GoTo :EOF 
) ) 
ECHO false 
false
GoTo :EOF
```

It is not even outputting the `echo true`.

I've tried with `EXIT /b 0` instead of `GoTo :EOF` but with the same result.

So what am I missing here? Why the program, when called from Java, keeps going even though it has a `GoTo :EOF`?
Why the different outputs? Is it a Java thing? Is it a batch thing?

## **UPDATE**:

After all the file from where variable were being loaded is relative to the command line location instead of the bat location.

Comment: Are you seriously asking us to explain what is happening based upon the content/definition of two variables, `%x%` and `%y%`, but not show us any code whatsoever to show exactly how those variables may be getting assigned a value? Also perhaps it would be easier for you, if you do it like this, **1.** `Set "response=FALSE"`, **2.** `If Defined x If Defined y Set "response=TRUE"`, **3.** `Echo %response%`, **4.** `Pause`, and **5.** `GoTo :EOF`.

Comment: `Process pr = rt.exec(processPath + " " + args[0] + " " + args[1]);` was my first conjecture. `ProcessBuilder` is indeed a better way against some pitfalls.

Comment: Answering your question and editing the original post made me wonder. After all, my mistake. The file did not exist because was being considered the relative path from where the command line was running instead of where the bat file was. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JoopEggen I read the rzwitserloot answer and definitely going to change. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you said it: "It is not even outputting the echo true". When you add debug lines, it.. helps to think for a second about what it means. 'x' is not defined, or 'y' is not defined (or most likely both are not defined).

You can manage the environment of the spawned process, use `ProcessBuilder`, and before launching (with e.g. `start()`), first set up the environment; for example with `pb.environment.put("x", "hello");`.

Why are you running batch scripts from java, though? They were bad technology back in the 80s, and there are a ton of alternatives available at this point. If you explain what you're trying to accomplish by farming work out to a batch file, perhaps an enterprising SO reader can make some useful suggestions.